# Why are my standard error values showing as NA?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Here is my reproducible sample:

```
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(Participant=1:20, 
                  Environment=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  Condition=rep(LETTERS[25:26], n/2),
                  Gate= sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
                  Block = sample(1:2, n, replace=TRUE),
                  Sound=rep(LETTERS[3:4], n/2),
                  Correct=sample(0:1, n, replace=TRUE)
)
```

From this dataset, I am trying to analyze at the participant-level, not the item-level. I Am trying to achieve this by transforming the dataset like this:

```
Participant_Data<- dat%>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound, Participant) %>% 
  summarize(Accuracy = mean(Correct), 
            se = sd(Correct)/sqrt(length(Correct)))
```

Then I am making a graph with this new dataset:

```
Participant_Data%>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound) %>%
  summarize(Proportion_Correct = mean(Accuracy),
            standarderror = sd(Proportion_Correct)/sqrt(length(Proportion_Correct))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Gate, y = Proportion_Correct, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Proportion_Correct - standarderror, ymax = Proportion_Correct + standarderror), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  facet_wrap(~Condition) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

But as you will see, my error values are coming up as NA, and therefore are not showing up on my graph. Let me know if you can see what I am not seeing, and thanks in advance!

Comment: You are grouping by so many columns that some of those groups only have one value. You can't calculate the standard deviation of a single value, ie `sd(5)` is NA. It's unclear what you would want to calculate in that case.

Comment: As you are computing `Proportion_Correct` as mean(Accuracy), to me `standarderror = sd(Accuracy, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())` looks like the natural way to  compute the standard error.

Comment: If you need to get something numeric there, it is not uncommon to infer `0` when there is only 1 datum; in that case, you can either do `se = if (n() < 2) 0 else sd(.)/sqrt(.)` or `se = coalesce(sd(.)/sqrt(.), 0)`. Granted, `0` is very different analytically, as it means 2 or more data are invariant, whereas now you could be confounding it with "insufficient data to calculate stddev". With that in mind, I think MrFlick's point is more salient: you may be over-grouping or under-sampling.

Comment: @MrFlick Then increasing the n on my reproducible sample should fix the problem, no? But when i do this, my error bars are still not there. I am trying to show the variation between each participant's accuracy at each gate

Comment: Thanks everyone, @stefan 's solution was the best fit. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @MrFlick in the comments the issue is that using `sd(Proportion_Correct)` you are trying to compute a standard deviation for a vector of length 1 which will return `NA`.

Instead I would suggest to compute the standard error as `sd(Accuracy, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n())` which looks more like the natural way to compute the standard error given that `Proportion_Correct` is computed as `mean(Accuracy)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Participant_Data1 <- Participant_Data%>% 
  group_by(Condition, Gate, Sound) %>%
  summarize(Proportion_Correct = mean(Accuracy),
            standarderror = sd(Accuracy, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n()))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Condition', 'Gate'. You can override using
#> the `.groups` argument.

ggplot(Participant_Data1, aes(x = Gate, y = Proportion_Correct, color = Sound, group = Sound)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Proportion_Correct - standarderror, ymax = Proportion_Correct + standarderror), color = "Black", size = .15, width = .3) + 
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+ 
  facet_wrap(~Condition) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]